# Executing a method from a thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Okay, so I've basically done the hardest workaround I could think of for the program that I'm working on and now have everything working....except the program itself.

So, here's the code I'm working with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new thread2());
        public void run() {
            thread.start();
            double startTime = System.nanoTime();
            SortingStuff ss = new SortingStuff();
            ss.setVisible(true);
            double endTime = System.nanoTime();
            double elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("This operation took " + elapsedTime + " nanoseconds, which is :" + ((elapsedTime / 1000000) / 1000) + " seconds."); // This will be better later
        }
    });
}
```

And then the thread2 runnable is something like this:

```
public static class thread2 implements Runnable{
public void run() {
    System.out.println("thread " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Now, if I wanted to call a static method from the thread created, how could I go about doing that?  I have a method called "bubbleSort" that I just can't get to work within the created thread.  Help?

```
    public static void bubbleSort(final String numbers[], final JButton numButton[]){
```

//Is the skeleton for the method, however I can't put it in the run area, and I can't seem to access the other thread from outside of where it's run.  UGH!

./Frustrated

Comment: where is `bubbleSort` defined, in which class?

Comment: It's defined in the top-level class, known as sortingStuff

Comment: The full- unabridged code for this program is available here:  http://ideone.com/RORWD  At present there's a LOT of unused imports that will be used later on.

Comment: why can't you get get it to work, what error do you get?

Comment: What happens when you try `SortingStuff.bubbleSort(...)`? If `bubbleSort` is a static method inside `SortingStuff`, there should be no problem with that.

Comment: At present if I run it it will use the thread.sleep() which will interrupt the Swing EDT.  Thus I'm trying to run the method in another thread so I can pause just that thread and let the swing EDT go unmolested.

Comment: please avoid using class names starting with lowercase letter

Comment: Here's another update to my present code.  http://ideone.com/gNOVw  Okay, the expected action that I want: When the user clicks "bubble sort" (only sort implemented at present") the loop will show (by changing the color of buttons background to red) when 2 items are about to be swapped.  I can do the color change.  I can't make Swing pause without messing up the EDT.

Comment: My basic idea of a "workaround" was to make another thread and run in that.  But I have no idea what to do with the other thread that I've made, since I can't simply tell the program "execute bubbleSort in Thread-0 rather than in thread AWT-EventQueue-0".  That's my question... But I have no idea how to phrase that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a static method from a class, even one that implements runnable, will not run on that thread, it will run from whichever thread called the static method.  Anything that you want to happen in that thread needs to get called from `run()`.

```
thread2 mythread = new thread2();
new Thread(mythread).start(); //Spawns new thread
thread2.bubbleSort(args); //Runs in this thread, not the spawned one
```

In response to the comment, I assume you were having problems because you couldn't pass your arguments to the run method.  You need to get that data to the thread either before it starts, or through some sort of data `stream(file, socket, etc)`.  Here I use the constructor, but it can also be done with a `setData(data here)` function.

```
public class Example implements Runnable {
    private dataObject args;

    public Example(dataObject input) {
        args = input;
    }
    public void dosort(dataObject sortArg){contents}

    public void run() {
        dosort(args);
    }
}

public static void main(stuff) { 
    Example myExample = new Example(data);
    //alternate example
    //myExample.setData(data);
    new Thread(myExample).start();
}
```